# C# Excel document - Register variables

Tags: c#, office-interop

I was wondering if there is a way to register variables in an xls document created with the C# office SDK.

I made an excel plugin which can create two types of xls documents. You can save this document and when you open it, i want excel to know if the document has been created using the plugin. I want excel plugin to enable/disable plugin buttons according to it.

I actually do it by a trivial sheet comparison and I want to know if this could be simplified by saving an invisible variable somewhere in the document (xlsx is a kind of zip archive).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: unfortunately Excel files don't have `Document.Variables` collection like Word documents. They still have the [`.CustomDocumentProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhxe2d75.aspx) collection, but those can be viewed by anyone. Maybe this can help http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/53159-Hidden-variables-in-Excel-(Excel-97)

Comment: I just don't want values to be registered in a sheet. In doc properties that will be ok. Thank you

Comment: We do this by adding Named Ranges in the Excel file, and a (hidden) worksheet containing the values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your question I learned something new:

```
Excel.Name name = thisWorkbook.Names.Add(Name:"a", RefersTo:"=#NAME?", Visible:false);
name.Comment = "some hidden value";

Debug.Print(thisWorkbook.Names["a"].Comment);
```

If you put any value in `RefersTo`, it can be seen in an Excel formula like `=a`